# Can I use the same local variables for two different events in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am a beginner with programming, so I'm sorry if this is a simple question. My program generates a random math problem (in addition) upon starting the application. The user enters what he/she believes is the answer. Next, the user clicks a button and text is displayed indicating whether the user's answer in correct or not.

I used the variables  number1 and number2 in the Form Load event. How can I easily use them again in the button click event?

(Hopefully my code demonstrates what I was trying to do).....

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //New Method
    private void GenerateRandoms()
    {
        // create random number variable
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        int number1; 
        int number2; 

        number1 = randomNumber.Next(100, 501);
        number2 = randomNumber.Next(100, 501);

        randomProblemLeft.Text = number1.ToString();
        randomProblemRight.Text = number2.ToString(); 
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Call created method so random numbers are generated once form loads.
        GenerateRandoms();
    }

    private void checkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rightAnswer; //The correct answer for the addition problem
        int theirAnswer; // The answer given by the user

        theirAnswer = int.Parse(answerInput.Text);

        rightAnswer = (number1 + number2); //Trying to reuse these variables from first event????????????

        if (rightAnswer == theirAnswer)
        {
            checkOutput.Text = "Yes, that is the correct answer!";
        }
        else
        {
            checkOutput.Text = "Sorry, that is incorrect!";
        }
    }

    private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        answerInput.Text = "";
        checkOutput.Text = "";
        GenerateRandoms();
    }

    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you philologon!!! I'm glad you taught me something new today :)

Comment: Whichever answer you think is most on-point, you should "accept" that answer by clicking the "Accepted Answer" icon under the votes button on the left.  You are not able to do this until your question is at least 10 minutes old.

Comment: Oh ok, Sorry, I didn't know that. I was looking for a way to "close" the question. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local variables disappear as soon as they go out of scope (i.e. after the closing curly brace of the block where the local is declared is reached). Their values get discarded, with no way to recover them. That is why locals will not work in this case: you need to make them *instance* variables.

Declare the variables as private on the class level, remove the declaration from the method, and use instance variables in any of your methods:

```
private int number1; // Declared at the form level
private int number2; 
private void GenerateRandoms()
{
    // create random number variable
    Random randomNumber = new Random();
    number1 = randomNumber.Next(100, 501);
    number2 = randomNumber.Next(100, 501);
    ...
}
private void checkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int answer = number1 + number2;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm glad you showed me that :) I was unaware it worked that way, but you learn something new everyday I suppose

Comment: @user2852838 This is very fundamental - classes use this all the time. Be careful using too many of these in your user interface classes, though. It's fine in a school assignment, but in production code you really want your GUI (i.e. the form) separate from your data model (i.e. `number1` and `number2`) as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am loving this site. Such a great community of people who genuinely care :)

Answer (score 0):

the button click event actually has its own scope so you have a couple options. First declare variables number1 and number2 again in the button click event.

If you were to want the values to persist for some reason then you would want to declare number1 and number2 in the scope of the class. this would make them part of the object you create.

example

```
public class Form1()
{
   private int number1;
   private int number2;

   //your functions here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would make them "global" to the Form1 class by putting them at the same bracket level as the methods. This makes them member fields:

```
class Form1 
{
   private int number1; 
   private int number2; 
   // . . . the rest of the class goes here –
}
```

Doing it this way makes them available (in scope) to all of your classes methods.  Putting the 'private' keyword on there makes it so no one else can access them.